# Syntax error or access violation: 1067 while installing module

Tags: database

I am getting error while installing custom module. please let me know where am i doing wrong.

```
function product_enquiry_schema() {
  $schema['product_enquiry'] = array(
    'description'=>'product enquiry',
    'fields'=>array(
      'id' => array(
        'description'=>'primary key value',
        'type'=>'serial'
      ),
      'product_id'=>array(
        'description'=>'product\'s id',
        'type'=>'int',
        'default'=>0
      ),
      'email'=>array(
        'type'=>'varchar',
        'length'=>100
      ),
      'message'=>array(
        'type'=>'varchar',
        'length'=>255
      ),
      'status'=>array(
        'type'=>'int',
        'default'=>1
      )
    )
  );

  return $schema;
}
```

Comment: please provide more information on error, which you're getting in "Recent Log Messages". As I can see some of the attributes are missing in your schema. Check [schema definition example](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.install/function/node_schema/7.x) for ref.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. here is the response error : PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'id': CREATE TABLE {product_enquiry} ( `id` INT unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment DEFAULT 0, `product_id` INT DEFAULT 0, `email` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '', `message` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '', `status` INT DEFAULT 0, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COMMENT 'product enquiry'; Array ( ) in db_create_table() (line 2776 of D:\drupal_new\includes\database\database.inc).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the default value of id column or simple replace the above code with the following one:

```
'id' => array(
        'description'=>'primary key value',
        'type'=>'serial'
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,   
 ),
```